# How do I access a hard drive from a live CD?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, live-cd

How can I access my hard drive from a Live CD? As far as I can tell the hard drive can only be accessed via `/media/longnumberhere` after its been mounted. Is there a way to access the hard drive a drive instead? (so it can be accessed by `/dev/hda`)

Answer (score 2):

*Not sure what this has to do with shredding...*

To mount a drive in this manner, first locate it using `sudo fdisk -l` in a terminal (within the LiveCD environment).

Then determine the drive/partition you want and mount it as usual with the `mount` command.