# error: unknown filesystem - what happened?

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

All the answered questions with this error seem to be partitioning ones.

I wasn't changing my partition at all, just copying some files.

I have a boatload of movies on my little Toshiba - equally partitioned with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

I grabbed a USB 3.0 cable and started the move of 110 GB of files to my external harddrive (There was only about 2.4GB available - so it was getting a little desperate).

Everything seemed to be working well. The job was only going to take the computer an hour, which I was reasonably impressed with.

I walked away, came back, and the computer was shut down.

I can't get the computer to load either OS, getting the

error: unknown file system

I'm starting to think that it might have been too much for the processor to send over  all at once, because I don't get the boot menu to choose which OS to use. I didn't think that had anything to do with Ubuntu, but I could be wrong.

I've tried a few of the methods other folks with the same error have used successfully with none of my own.

I'm running the computer through the usb drive of the Ubuntu 11.4 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Wow this is nasty.  Here is what I would do:

1. Boot from a live CD and mount your drive.  You can then take a look at it and get a better idea of what happened and if you can recover any data.  Once you are booted open up Nautilus or another file manager and look for the drive.  You may also find it through terminal by going to `/media/<your-user>/<drive-number>` or something similar.  [Here's a question that may help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43718/how-do-i-access-a-hard-drive-from-a-live-cd).
2. Once you've recovered any data, reinstall a new and supported version of Ubuntu.  11.04 is old and unsupported.